# FDTI libMPSSE I2C- Getting FT_IO_ERROR while using separate Reader & Writer Threads to read and write

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, i2c

I am trying to communicate with I2C device using FT232HL(libMPSSE dll). Separate threads are used for reading and writing the data. First write cycle happens successfully but then it gives FT_IO_ERROR.

I have followed AN_177_User_Guide_For_LibMPSSE-I2C.pdf while coding and have used semaphores for synchronization of threads.
    I couldn't find document on FT_IO_ERROR over the Internet. Please help me if you know about it.

Answer (score 1):

The I2C bus is half duplex.
It is thought that it is not necessary to distinguish read thread from write thread.

FT_IO_ERROR is a data transfer failure.
This is described on page 13 of the document you explained.

It is probably not a problem of the interface chip or the library, but whether the communication control is performed according to the command/response sequence of the device connected to the I2C bus.

Please check the communication specification of the I2C device being used.
In addition, make sure that the interface chip and the I2C device are correctly connected and communication is possible.

Comment: Reader and writer threads are separate because same code is used for SPI, UART(macro based decision). And read happens based on status of IRQ line controlled by the slave. As per description of FT_IO_ERROR, libMPSSE is failed to write/read please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Now that the problem is occurring, it is better to conduct the survey step by step.
For example, based on FTDI's I2C sample program, modify it for command/response of the I2C device used by you and check whether it can communicate in the simplest form.
After checking it, please consider the difference with the current program.

Comment: Hi Kunif, I got the reason of FT_IO_ERROR. (I checked source code of libMPSSE). If you are interested please have a look at [LibMPSSE-I2C.htm](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/SoftwareExamples/MPSSE/LibMPSSE-I2C.htm)

Comment: That's good. If it can be published, please describe the cause of the problem and how to solve it in addition to your question.